# jQuery .load() not in Opera 11, but working in IE8 and firefox

Tags: jquery, opera

The problem I am having is that the .load() function seems to be ignored? I am receiving no errors in the error log in DragonFly. The alert is just for debugging, and is working.

Strangely though, this works in IE8 as well as Fire Fox 10

I am current using jQuery 1.7.2 and opera 11.61.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //page defaulted to main
    $('#main').load('main.html');

    $('#menuAnchors > li > a').each(function(){}).           
    click(function(){        
        $('#main').load($(this).attr('href'));
        alert($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

The code above is targetting

```
<ul id ="menuAnchors" class ="menuItems">
<li><a id="menuASolarFlare" href="solarFlares.html" target="main">Solar Flares</a></li>
<li><a id="menuACurrencyConverter" href="currencyConverter.html" target="main">Currency Converter</a></li>
<li><a id="menuAXML" href="mydoc.xml" target="main">XML</a></li>
<li><a id="menuAXML" href="outPutxml" target="main">Section 1 - XML</a></li>
<li><a id="menuAMain" href="main.html" target="main">Main</a></li>
<li><a id="menuASmile" href="smile.html" target="main">Smile :D!</a></li>
<li><a id="menuAMedia" href="media.html" target="main">Media</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-Origin browser issue. Try deploying your HTML page on a webserver.

For more info: http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: When including the Access-Control-Allow-Origin, jquery .load() works, but all loaded content is opened in a new tab, even in FF. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: you need to wait load method to complete try $(document).ready(function(){
    //page defaulted to main
    $('#main').load('main.html', function(){

     $('#menuAnchors > li > a').each(function(){}).           
     click(function(e){    
      e.preventDefault();    
         $('#main').load($(this).attr('href'));
         alert($(this).attr('href'));
         return false;
     });
    });
});